Power BI Rest API Dataset Refresh isn't updating entire model
I am trying to use the REST API Dataset Refresh to programmatically update my datasets that are setup with incremental refresh.  The rest api successfully kicks off the refresh of the models but for whatever reason it's not completely updating my models.
I have data for 5 years.  The initial refresh should update all 5 years, and then theoretically update whatever changes in the future.
However, in my test model it updated 4 years completely but the missed July and AUgust of this year.  I was able to manually update July and August using Tabular Editor.  But I was under the impression that this should update the entire model up to yesterday.
My Incremental Refresh options in my model are setup as follows:

and now my code that i'm using to call the initial refresh is below.  I want it to update the entire model all at once.  Please let me know what I'm missing.
  RestClient client = new RestClient($"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/{workspaceGUID}/datasets/{datasetGUID}/refreshes");
  RestRequest request = new RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);

  request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);

  request.AddJsonBody(new
  {
      type = "full",
      commitMode = "transactional",
      applyRefreshPolicy = false
  });

  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


When we refresh the dataset using REST API, it should update the data till yesterday. You mentioned that when you refresh in tabular editor it's working fine. Could you please check when you refresh the dataset in Power BI Service it's working fine or the July, August data is still missing in the service also ?

Earlier I faced similar kind of issue, but for me I also need to hit the Update DataSource REST API to get the latest data as I wasn't using enhanced dataset metadata. Refer to the important section in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources-in-group and see if it can fix your issue? LMK if you're still facing the issue
